How to dynamically reference correct cell
I have a spreadsheet where one column lists products and their variations and another column shows a price for each product. Ex:

I need a column that calculates the price difference between a variation and the base product. Each product has a different number of variations.
Is there a way to calculate this price difference and autofill the formula and make sure that that base model reference adjusts correctly?


Here is one way of doing this, provided you are using MS365


=LET(x, TEXTSPLIT(A2:A10,CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,65)),,1), y, B2:B10, y-XLOOKUP(x, x, y))



I would use a helper column to extract the model group from the Model #.
I used the formula =LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-1)
Then I did a vlookup to pull the first of that group and subtract that from the row's model #'s price. You could reference the helper column as well instead of extracting the model group from the model # in the vlookup, it'd be a cleaner formula but to show how everything connects I have it this way.
=IFERROR(C2-VLOOKUP(LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-1),$A$1:C1,3,0),0)
=IFERROR(C2-VLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:C1,3,0),0)


Thank you so much! It turned out much easier than I thought it would be.

I'm glad you found my answer helpful and sufficient for your problem. The other answer is also very good and contains a lot of this into the formula, so if you can use helper columns or don't like to display it, that works well. Sometimes it's easier to see the information segregated like this for other purposes like the average price per model group or so on.
